# Showing that $\{x:u(x)\le v(x)\}$ is measurable where $u,v$ are measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $u,v$ be measurable functions from a measurable space $(X,\cal{A})$ to $(\mathbb{\bar{R}},\cal{B}(\mathbb{\bar{R}}))$. How can I prove that $\{x:u(x)\le v(x)\}$ is in $\cal{A}$? It is of course immediate if $v(x)-u(x)$ is defined, but what if we happen to get $\infty-\infty$?

Is there a proof of this?

Comment: You can split the set into two parts, which contains the points making $v(x)=\infty$ and the points $v(x) < \infty$. The second part result directly from $u(x)-v(x)$ and the first part results from the intersection of $\{x|u(x)\leq \infty\}$ and $\{x|v(x) = \infty\}$

Answer (score 1):

You may use density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to show $$\{x: u(x)\leq v(x) \} = \cup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} A_q$$ where $A_q =\{x: u(x) \leq q\} \cap \{x: v(x) \geq q\}$.

Comment: A good idea. But it misses points where $u(x)=v(x)$ and is irrational.  Do your idea on the complement, where $u(x) > v(x)$.  Then there is always a rational in there.

Comment: ah yes, thank you